# How to load the correct ODP .NET DLL

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit, odp.net, odac

I have a project that uses ODP .NET version 11 to connect to a database. There are two versions available from Oracle, one for 32 and another for 64 bit.

If I want to compile this project as AnyCPU, how do I get the project at runtime to pick the right version of the Oracle.DataAccess.dll?

I don't want to rely on the project picking up the correct DLL from the GAC, I'd rather reference my DLLs from within my project.

Comment: Don't include both then.

Comment: Won't it crash when running as 32-bit if I only include the 64-bit DLL? I want to use AnyCPU. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Include the 32 bit version and compile to Any CPU. You can't have it both ways unfortunately.  Also you may need to enable running as 32 bit in the app pool itself

Comment: Why not have two versions of the executable, one 32 bit and one 64 bit.

Comment: @jussij  why incur more application maintenance overhear than necessary?

Comment: @David for no other reason than to get a true 64 bit application for the 64 bit platform. If the OP is happy to run a 32 bit app on the both platforms, then naturally that is easiest solution. But if there is a real advantage to running a true 64 bit application on the 64 bit machine then there is no other option.